# html5 videos not playing on iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, html, .htaccess, video

I have an issue with playing my html5 videos on iOS devices, namely iPhone 7.0 and iPad 7.0.4 currently the iPad is showing just the empty container and on iPhone it has the play button with a line through it. What could this mean?

I've put the following in the .htaccess file -

```
AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used to integrate mp4-videos this way:

```
<video src="path/to/file.mp4" poster="thumbnail.jpg" type="video/mp4" width="640" controls autobuffer />
```

My videos are MP4/H.264, Baseline profile, 480×360

Never had an issue with this. Maybe the path to your video isn't correct.

Comment: if my dimensions are 1280 × 720 for the mp4 does this affect it in anyway?

Comment: Actually i'm not aware of the capabilities of the named iPhone/iPad. Have a look at the suggestions from [Zencoder] (http://blog.zencoder.com/2010/09/30/how-to-encode-video-for-mobile-use/)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I realised I had the .htaccess file in the dev.domain.com folder and it needed to be in the main domains public htaccess. All fixed now but thanks again

Comment: help me with the path(how to enter the path)